# Select the value tag of the element selected by class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, element

I have a page that has a whole bunch of buttons

```
<button value=<?php val?> class='hot' >Hot</button>
```

and Im selecting them by class because the values will all be different. Im trying to have them, on click, alert the value, but I can't figure out how to access the value field.

My function is

```
$(".hot").click(function() {
});
```

and I tried to access it(after much time spent googling) using:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
```

resulting in

```
$(".hot").click(function() {
     $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
});
```

however, when I alert that, it just says undefined.

And ideas would be awesome! Im pretty familiar with php, but javascript and JQuery are pretty new to me, so links and good explanations are really appreciated, not just an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.val()`:

```
$(".hot").click(function() {
   var valueOfButton = $(this).val();
});
```

Please also see this other SO question for the difference between `.val()` and `.attr('value')`: [What's the difference between jQuery .val() and .attr('value')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837133/whats-the-difference-bewteen-jquery-val-and-attrvalue)

Comment: This works, so great! However, what would I do if I wanted a different elemetn in it? Like ad id or href? Just for future reference.

Comment: You can use `$("#blah")` for id, and `$("[href]")` for element attributes. I recommend the very helpful jQuery documentation :) http://docs.jquery.com/

Comment: But would that get the id of the currently clicked class?

Comment: @Samuraisoulification you want to know about [jQuery.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: You could use what @moonwave99 has and call `.attr('id')`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need:

```
$(".hot").click(function(e) {
   alert( $(this).attr('value') );
});
```

Comment: Ghostly downwoters are ghostly.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one...It will alert the value of button which was clicked...

```
$(".hot").click(function() {
alert($(this).val());
});
```