# Attribute value VS property value

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an `<input>` element which is loaded with a default value. Later on, i change that value via jQuery's `input.val("different value")`.

When I console.log() the  element, I see this in firebug:

```
Object[input.cs_required.form-control.input-sm property value = "12/29/2014" attribute value = "12/02/2014"]
```

- Why are there two different values assigned to the input?
- What is the
  difference between the property value and the attribute value?
- Should
  I be concerned?

Comment: Not sure why they are different but Attributes are defined by HTML and Properties are defined by DOM.

Comment: I think there is a good explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258469/what-is-the-difference-between-attribute-and-property)

Comment: a property, in general, is a setter (method) and getter (method) that is 'used' as a 'field/member', or in right or left value assignemnt; like any other method, it runs procedural code in the respective method that is called, depending whether you are setting to or getting from. Attributes, are type describers.. use primarily for annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example of the difference:

`jQuery('#something').val()` changes the *.value property.
`jQuery('#something').attr('value','neValue')` changes the attribute on that component.

There is an important difference between the two. Take a look at this for more info.

[What's the difference between jQuery .val() and .attr('value')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837133/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-val-and-attrvalue)

The only thing you have to worry about is whether you are using/assigning/utilizing the correct item - `property or attribute`.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you are providing a default value via the `value` HTML attribute. That will be the initial value of the DOM element's `value` **property**. Changing the *propery* does not affect the attribute.

The value of HTML attributes is often used as initial value for the corresponding DOM property.