# Dynamic button event getting undefined id message on Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I am trying to creat dynamic buttons and click event. Creating dynamic button is working but when I cliked it I am getting undefined message. What is my wrong? Sorry my lang. Thx in advance. My code is below:

```
$(function(){
   var i = 1;

$('button').on('click',function(){
      var r= $('<input type="button" class="dinamik" value="new button '+ i +' "/>');
      $("body").append(r);
      i++;
   });
});

    $(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.dinamik', function(){
           var valueDeger = $(this).find('.dinamik').attr('value');
           alert("Value değeri: " + valueDeger);
    });
});
```

[Demo is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SP8de/131/)

Comment: You have to delegate click event for `.dynamic` element. Search for one of the thousand hundreds duplicate...

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: The problem was unrelated to the title, so was not a duplicate of those answers. it was simply misuse of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the click event handler, `this` referes to the button itself, there is no need to use `find` method:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.dinamik', function(){
       var valueDeger = $(this).attr('value');
       alert("Value değeri: " + valueDeger);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SP8de/133/).

---

*Using `val()` method instead of `attr('value')` is recommended, see this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4837133/3971911)*.

Comment: At last an actual explanation +1 :)

Comment: `val()` is preferable to `attr()` for value properties. Sometimes you need to go beyond the initial bug and encourage good practices :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I've add it to the answer as a side note `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
var valueDeger = $(this).find('.dinamik').attr('value');
```

to this:

```
var valueDeger = $(this).val(); // or this.value;
```

---

The issue is `$(this)` refers to the clicked element which is your `input[type="button"]` and you are trying to find the `.find('.dinamik')` in it, which is not there, so that's why it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SP8de/134/)

Try this one

```
$(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        var r= $('<input type="button" class="dinamik" value="new button '+ i +' "/>');
        $("body").append(r);
        i++;
    });
});

$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.dinamik', function(){
        var valueDeger = $(this).val();
        alert("Value değeri: " + valueDeger);
    });
});
```

Comment: `val()` is preferable to `attr()` for value properties. Sometimes you need to go beyond the initial bug and encourage good practices :)

Comment: yes u are write, thank u @TrueBlueAussie

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
var valueDeger = $(this).find('.dinamik').attr('value');
```

To

```
var valueDeger = $(this).val();
```

Comment: When I post at that time your answer is not present that's why I posted