# Cannot change value of input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where these 3 things are **simultaneously** true. What's going on?

This is the element in the dom:

```
<input id="destroy_vehicle_section_4" name="driver[workables_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="text" value="1">
```

After changing the attribute value with JQuery's val method (or javascript's getElementById().value), using the console:

```
> $("#destroy_vehicle_section_4").val()
<- "test"
```

...The DOM remains the same.

I can also change the value with JQuery's attr method,

```
> $("#destroy_vehicle_section_4").attr("value")
<- "hey"
```

The DOM remains the same, and the 2nd call also still show "test"

How is this possible?

It's meaning that my attempts to change the input using jQuery are failing.

---

N.B: Am using jQuery Mobile.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the poor explanation. I first set using attr("value", "hey") and val("test"), neither console call changed the DOM element. However if you run the "Getter" lines in the console, you get the above

Comment: *`After changing the attribute value with JQuery's val method`* you're not *changing* it, you're getting it. *`3 things are simultaneously true`* what?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837133/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-val-and-attrvalue

Comment: To *get* (retrieve) a value you use jQuery's `.val()`

To *set* a value you need to pass a variable to the argument `.val("hey")`

Comment: So where do "test" and "hey" come from?

Answer (score 1):

To *get* a value you use jQuery's `.val()`
To *set* a value you need to pass a variable to the argument `.val("hey")`

To *get* an attribute value you use jQuery's `.attr("value")`
To *set* an attribute value you need to set the second argument as `.attr("value", "hey")`

The above applies also for `.prop()` method.
How to properly use each of those methods I suggest you to refer to the official jQuery documentation.

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation. I set using attr("value", "hey") and val("test"), neither console call changed the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your functions in an event like onclick, onload or inside a document.ready() or simply

```
$(function(){

//your functions here...

});
```

Comment: Usually they are fired in a document.ready() - and it's not working then - but for demonstration I used the console.