# when to use .val() vs attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

From my understanding .attr() and .val() are the same except .attr() 
returns the initial value/ the value in the markup, where as 
the .val() returns the     current value. I did a little
experiment though and that brought up more questions then answers.
I know there is a duplicate but it didn't seem to fully answer my question

```
    var attrib=$('#overlay').attr('style');
    //returned  the initial value "display: none;"
    //then I changed the value with
     var test= $('#overlay').attr('style', 'display: block');
    // returned "display: block;"
    //I then pulled back up the value with .attr()
    var test2= $('#overlay').attr('style');
    /* returned "display: block;", 
    it returned the current value not the one in the markup */
```

So what exactly is the difference?

Comment: val is for form and get the value of an input, and ttr is any of html attibute of a tag

Comment: `From my understanding .attr() and .val() are the same` - your understanding is *very* wrong.

Comment: Here you have the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837133/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-val-and-attrvalue

Answer (score 2):

.val() is used to get the value associated with any html tag and attr() is used to fetch the attributes like id, class, disabled etc. val() works for textbox, text, hidden but attr works for p div table, text, textarea and so on..