# Material Design Lite slider update

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design-lite

I've been trying to use [MDL](https://getmdl.io/) [sliders](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#sliders-section) to make my website, but I get a problem.
Everything is working, however, when I try to change the value of the slider through [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), the "bar" of the slider isn't synced as you can see here :

[image]

or the "blue circle" isn't colored (note that the default value is the minimum one which disables the color of the slider and when I update it, it doesn't put the color back) :

[image]

The code I'm using to change sliders value:

```
  $("#mySlider").val(10);
```

But it doesn't update the graphical part, only the value.

This is the property which handles the bar color :

[image]

**Minimal reproducible example:**

To reproduce this, insert a [slider](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#sliders-section) with a default value then change it using the above javascript code to change the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't change `value` like that, there is a native way:

```js
$('#click').on('click', function() {
  $('#mySlider').get(0).MaterialSlider.change(10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<input class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" id="mySlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="25" tabindex="0">

<button id="click" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised">
  Update
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the value attribute is used to set a slider's initial value, it should not be used to modify the value programmatically; instead, use the MDL change() method. For example, assuming that slider1 is a slider object and newvalue is a variable containing the desired value, do not use slider1.value = newvalue; instead, use slider1.MaterialSlider.change(newvalue)

Comment: [What's the difference between jQuery .val() and .attr('value')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837133/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-val-and-attrvalue)